# Missing parameter error even if already provided in AWS SQS PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I'm getting this error even if I already provided a `MessageGroupId` parameter:

> AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxx/xxx.fifo` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: SenderM (truncated...) MissingParameter (client): The request must contain the parameter MessageGroupId. - SenderMissingParameterThe request must contain the parameter MessageGroupId ...

Here's a sample code:

```
$client = new Aws\Sqs\SqsClient([    
    'region' => 'us-west-2',
    'version' => '2012-11-05',
    'MessageGroupId' => 'testGroup',
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => 'xxx',
        'secret' => 'xxx'
    ]
]);

$params = [
    'MessageBody' => 'foo',
    'QueueUrl' => 'https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxx/xxx.fifo'
];


try {
    $result = $client->sendMessage($params);
    var_dump($result);
} catch (Aws\Exception\AwsException $e) {    
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know why I put `MessageGroupId` in the `SqsClient()` parameter when it should've been in the `sendMessage()` `$params` array.